# How to change date format using phpexcel while importing data from excel?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, date, phpmyadmin

i have excel file (.xls) and in that file I have date field with format like this : `21/07/1989`

i try to upload to database (phpmyadmin) in localhost, after upload date change format from `21/07/1989` to **210789**

i want to ask how to change the format date in phpmyadmin from `210789` to **21/07/1989**

in database (phpmyadmin) type of date i set to text but not effect

this my code for import file xls to database :

```
<?php
 //export.php
 if(!empty($_FILES["excel_file"]))
 {
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myname_database");

     mysqli_query($connect,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
      $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["excel_file"]["name"]);
      if($file_array[1] == "xls")
      {  
           include("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
           $output = '';
           $output .= "
           <label class='text-success'>Data Inserted</label>
                <table class='table table-bordered'>
                     <tr>  
                          <th>No</th>
                          <th>Nama</th>
                          <th>Date of birth</th>
                     </tr>
                     ";
           $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"]);
           foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
           {
                $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
                for($row=1; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
                {
                     $no = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
                     $nama = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
                     $date_birth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
                     $query = "
                     INSERT INTO myname_table
                     (no, nama, date_birth)
                     VALUES ('".$no."', '".$nama."', '".$date_birth."')
                     ";
                     mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                     $output .= '
                     <tr>
                          <td>'.$no.'</td>
                          <td>'.$name.'</td>
                          <td>'.$date_birth.'</td>

                     </tr>
                     ';
                }
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
      }
      else
      {
         echo '<label class="text-danger">Invalid File</label>';
      }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hav you tried to change columns in excel from date to text add date as text  and then upload

Comment: thank you sir, for your reply, i have try to change column date in excel to text, but so as I said above the format date change to "210789". I want dates that look like this sir:

21/07/1989

Comment: Language improvements, bold on desired date formats

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulated value again at database, you should prefer to format the value when retrieving it from excel.

A `getValue()` call on a field containing a date should return a value like `210789`. To get a formatted date string, you need to call `getFormattedValue()` instead. To identify if a cell contains an MS serialized datetime stamp, you can use a call to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()`.

```
$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row);
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
   echo $cell->getFormattedValue();
} else {
    echo $cell->getValue();
}
```